# Automatically recieve new Amazon S3 for APS reporting secret access key

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am looking for an alternative way to recieve the new secret access key from amazon publisher services every 90 days/whenever a new one is available. Right now the only way I see is to get it manually via the GUI every 90 days.

[image: Credentials in the GUI (taken from the documentation]

I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Do they have an API? A quick web search failed to reveal an API for Amazon APS.

Comment: No, there does not seem to be an API especially for APS. I would guess that its fully embedded in AWS.

Comment: It is not an AWS service. It might use AWS behind-the-scenes (as do half the big websites on the Internet), but **Amazon Publisher Services** comes from the Retail side of Amazon, not AWS.

Comment: Were having the same issue.
There is no APS API - from their FAQ:

"Is there a reporting API?"
"Currently, there is no reporting API and it is not on our roadmap for 2022, however you can access reporting through our S3 services."

if you have an AMS user then you can read it yourself here: 
https://ams.amazon.com/webpublisher/uam/docs/uam-aps-reporting.html